# How to notify client app on disconnecting namedpipe from server?

Tags: named-pipes

Basically I am using named Pipe mechanism for Client/Server Interaction. Issue I am facing when I abruptly close Server which simply disconnect the named Pipe. Since there is no Event Handler for handling the error message from Server Side, It simply waits for some action to occur, on that action occurrence only it knows the state of connection and tries to reconnect. My requirement is, as soon as server goes down, my client side app just simply get notified and tries to connect to server until the server didn't come back. 
Code for connecting to server.

```
        this._handle =
        CreateFile(this._pipeName,
                   GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                   0,
                   IntPtr.Zero,
                   OPEN_EXISTING,
                   FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                   IntPtr.Zero);

        // Could not create handle - server probably not running
        if (this._handle.IsInvalid)
            return;

        this._connected = true;
        // Start listening for messages
        this._readThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Read));
        this._readThread.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

`ReadFile` and `WriteFile` will return false you need to check `GetLastError()` to see why the call failed. You could create a thread that checks the pipe every second via `PeekNamedPipe` or `GetNamedPipeInfo`.